# Two setState being enacted at the same time updating page separately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a graph using the react-plotly library. The data from the graph is being queried from an API endpoint.

The service file is shown below

```
import React from 'react'

export default async function GetStockData(token,ticker,setData, setSuccess) {

    var myHeaders = new Headers();

    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("Tick", ticker);


    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };


  
    await fetch("https://abc.azurewebsites.net/api/stocks", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => setData(JSON.parse(response.content))
    
   
  }
```

I am still the add error handling. I have fixed the ticker to a value that I know works for now.

This service is then called by the component below:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import GetStockData from '../Services/GetStockData'
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import { sampleData } from './sampleChartdata';
import AuthContext from "../Store/AuthContext";

export default function CandleStick() {

   const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

   const token = authCtx.token

   const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(sampleData);

   const [chartSuccess, setChartSuccess] = useState(false)

   const [preppedData, setpreppedData] = useState(null);

   const [layout, setlayout] = useState(null);

   const ticker = 'MSFT'

   const clickHandler = async()=>{

      await GetStockData(token,ticker,setChartData, setChartSuccess)

      const {data, preplayout} = dataPrep()

      setpreppedData(data)

      setlayout(preplayout)




   }

   const dataPrep =()=>{
  
      var dateData  = []

      var closeData = []

      var openData = []

      var lowData = []

      var highData = [] 
  
      for(var prop in chartData["Time Series (Daily)"]){

         dateData.push(prop)
         for(var prop2 in chartData["Time Series (Daily)"][prop]){
         if (prop2=="1. open"){ openData.push(chartData["Time Series (Daily)"][prop][prop2])}
         if (prop2=="2. high"){ highData.push(chartData["Time Series (Daily)"][prop][prop2])}
         if (prop2=="3. low"){ lowData.push(chartData["Time Series (Daily)"][prop][prop2])}
         if (prop2=="5. adjusted close"){ closeData.push(chartData["Time Series (Daily)"][prop][prop2])}
      }
  
    }

    var trace1 = {

      x: dateData,
      close:closeData,

      increasing: {line: {color: 'green'}},
      decreasing: {line: {color: 'red'}},

      high: highData,

  

      line: {color: 'rgba(31,119,180,1)'}, 

      low: lowData,

      open: openData,

      type: 'candlestick', 
      xaxis: 'x', 
      yaxis: 'y'
    };

    var data = [trace1]

    var layout = {
      dragmode: 'zoom', 
      margin: {
        r: 10, 
        t: 25, 
        b: 40, 
        l: 60
      }, 
      showlegend: false, 
      xaxis: {
        autorange: true, 
        domain: [0, 1], 
    
        title: 'Date', 
        type: 'date'
     }, 
     yaxis: {
       autorange: true, 
       domain: [0, 1], 
   
       type: 'linear'
     }
   };

   return {data , layout}

  } ;

  useEffect(() => {
     if (preppedData !== null) setIsDataLoaded(true);console.log(preppedData)
  }, [preppedData]);

  return (


    <>
       <div>{isDataLoaded? 
        <Plot 
        data={preppedData}
        layout={layout}>
        </Plot>: null}
       </div>
       <button onClick={()=>clickHandler()}>Refresh</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

There are probably a whole host of things that could be improved here. I am using too stateful variables for a start. I currently have a local store of data to use as a sample to prevent an error occurring prior to the request being made. Any comment on how to manage first render when awaiting web based content would be massively appreciated.

My core question relate to setChartData, setChartSuccess. On the press of the button, these are passed to the service file where they are updated simultaneously. However, the chartSuccess variable seems to update prior to ChartData. The jsx conditional triggers and renders the graph but it doesn't contain the latest preppedData. On pressing the button a second time the updated data appears. Am I making an error in the sequencing?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you can do 2 things to solve this. Either set success state inside the click handler and if the success state can't be moved to elsewhere as it might be used in some other place, you can have a new state variable and use it for the condition for render or not.

I'm showing you how to do it with the 2nd method here, but you can give 1st method a try if you don't have problem I mentioned.

So, your component code will look like this.

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import GetStockData from '../Services/GetStockData';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import { sampleData } from './sampleChartdata';
import AuthContext from '../Store/AuthContext';

export default function CandleStick() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  const token = authCtx.token;

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(sampleData);

  const [chartSuccess, setChartSuccess] = useState(false);

  const [preppedData, setpreppedData] = useState(null);

  const [layout, setlayout] = useState(null);

  const [isDataLoaded, setIsDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  const ticker = 'MSFT';

  const clickHandler = async () => {
    await GetStockData(token, ticker, setChartData, setChartSuccess);

    const { data, preplayout } = dataPrep();

    setpreppedData(data);

    setlayout(preplayout);

    setIsDataLoaded(true);
  };

  const dataPrep = () => {
    var dateData = [];

    var closeData = [];

    var openData = [];

    var lowData = [];

    var highData = [];

    for (var prop in chartData['Time Series (Daily)']) {
      dateData.push(prop);
      for (var prop2 in chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop]) {
        if (prop2 == '1. open') {
          openData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
        if (prop2 == '2. high') {
          highData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
        if (prop2 == '3. low') {
          lowData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
        if (prop2 == '5. adjusted close') {
          closeData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
      }
    }

    var trace1 = {
      x: dateData,
      close: closeData,

      increasing: { line: { color: 'green' } },
      decreasing: { line: { color: 'red' } },

      high: highData,

      line: { color: 'rgba(31,119,180,1)' },

      low: lowData,

      open: openData,

      type: 'candlestick',
      xaxis: 'x',
      yaxis: 'y',
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    var layout = {
      dragmode: 'zoom',
      margin: {
        r: 10,
        t: 25,
        b: 40,
        l: 60,
      },
      showlegend: false,
      xaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        domain: [0, 1],

        title: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
      },
      yaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        domain: [0, 1],

        type: 'linear',
      },
    };

    return { data, layout };
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {isDataLoaded ? <Plot data={preppedData} layout={layout}></Plot> : null}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler()}>Refresh</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**UPDATED as per requirement**

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import GetStockData from '../Services/GetStockData';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import { sampleData } from './sampleChartdata';
import AuthContext from '../Store/AuthContext';

export default function CandleStick() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  const token = authCtx.token;

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(sampleData);

  const [chartSuccess, setChartSuccess] = useState(false);

  const [preppedData, setpreppedData] = useState(null);

  const [layout, setlayout] = useState(null);

  const [isDataLoaded, setIsDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  const ticker = 'MSFT';

  const clickHandler = async () => {
    await GetStockData(token, ticker, setChartData, setChartSuccess);

    const { data, preplayout } = dataPrep();

    setpreppedData(data);

    setlayout(preplayout);
  };

  const dataPrep = () => {
    var dateData = [];

    var closeData = [];

    var openData = [];

    var lowData = [];

    var highData = [];

    for (var prop in chartData['Time Series (Daily)']) {
      dateData.push(prop);
      for (var prop2 in chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop]) {
        if (prop2 == '1. open') {
          openData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
        if (prop2 == '2. high') {
          highData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
        if (prop2 == '3. low') {
          lowData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
        if (prop2 == '5. adjusted close') {
          closeData.push(chartData['Time Series (Daily)'][prop][prop2]);
        }
      }
    }

    var trace1 = {
      x: dateData,
      close: closeData,

      increasing: { line: { color: 'green' } },
      decreasing: { line: { color: 'red' } },

      high: highData,

      line: { color: 'rgba(31,119,180,1)' },

      low: lowData,

      open: openData,

      type: 'candlestick',
      xaxis: 'x',
      yaxis: 'y',
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    var layout = {
      dragmode: 'zoom',
      margin: {
        r: 10,
        t: 25,
        b: 40,
        l: 60,
      },
      showlegend: false,
      xaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        domain: [0, 1],

        title: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
      },
      yaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        domain: [0, 1],

        type: 'linear',
      },
    };

    return { data, layout };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (preppedData !== null) setIsDataLoaded(true);
  }, [preppedData]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {isDataLoaded ? <Plot data={preppedData} layout={layout}></Plot> : null}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler()}>Refresh</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Milan! Implementing your solution above gives me the same outcome I currently have. I played around with your solution and made IsDataLoaded dependant on the success. i.e if(chartSucess){setIsDataLoaded(true). That solves my first issue of the sample data popping up. However, despite the console stating the fetch has completed the graph doesnt appear on the first click. The second click brings it up just fine. Any clue why it doesn't all come through on the first click? Thanks

Comment: If you are doing some dependent tasks like mentioned above, use it with useEffect. Can you update the question with the latest code

Comment: @Chris I have updated solution

Comment: thanks again for the help here. I am truly beyond confused. I see the logic in your solution but when I copy it in my issue persists. It would seem that the useeffect picks up the state change in preppedData, but when the setIsDataLoaded is set the Plot is still taking the previous version (sample data). I have put a console.log to check and on the first click it logs the sample data. Question updated.

Comment: you are still using chartSuccess for conditional rendering where's I'm using isDataLoaded for conditional rendering. Let me know if this works or else, I need to check the library on if it supports re-rendering on state update.

Comment: ahh.. very sorry - I hadn't update that. Updates made. chartSuccess is essentially decorative for now. I also tried a variant where I set the success state based on the promise. I though the delay may have been causing an issue. i.e setSuccess(response.isSuccessful). This still resulted in the same outcome. Thanks